# Send SMS using Java (GSM Dongle)

Tags: java, api, sms

I am trying to develop an application that would let me send an SMS using a GSM Dongle connected on the USB port. I have downloaded javaxcomm api and placed files in appropriate folders. Since my O.S. is Windows 7 (64 Bit), I have downloaded jdk's 32 bit version. However, I am still unable to move ahead. Currently I am stuck with a NoSuchPortException.

The error appears around this line:

```
portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(parameters.getPortName());
```

Here is the complete code.

```
public class SMSClient implements Runnable{

  public final static int SYNCHRONOUS=0;
  public final static int ASYNCHRONOUS=1;
  private Thread myThread=null;

  private int mode=-1;
  private String recipient=null;
  private String message=null;

  public int status=-1;
  public long messageNo=-1;


  public SMSClient(int mode) {
      this.mode=mode;
    }

  public int sendMessage (String recipient, String message){
    this.recipient=recipient;
    this.message=message;
    //System.out.println("recipient: " + recipient + " message: " + message);
    myThread = new Thread(this);
    myThread.start();
//    run();
    return status;
    }
    public void run(){

    Sender aSender = new Sender(recipient,message);

    try{
      //send message
          aSender.send ();

         // System.out.println("sending ... ");

      //in SYNCHRONOUS mode wait for return : 0 for OK,
      //-2 for timeout, -1 for other errors
      if (mode==SYNCHRONOUS) {
          while (aSender.status == -1){
            myThread.sleep (1000);
          }
      }
      if (aSender.status == 0) messageNo=aSender.messageNo ;

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    this.status=aSender.status ;

    aSender=null;


  }
}
```

Comment: When you put code (and put code you should) with your question, please follow these guidelines http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ankit Thanks... I will take care of the same in future...
I have downloaded the code from the below link:
[link]http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22
If you want, I can paste the entire code here...

Comment: It is always better to paste the code (at least the important parts of the code) so that the question stays meaningful for future visitors (even if the original website is not available in future)

Comment: Ankit, once again thanks for your help... I will surely take care of the same in future...